# SUBTOTAL more than 254 rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am auto generating a spreadsheet via VBA with budgetary data. The rows are variable. I use the following code for an R1C1 formula. Variable r is a row counter.

```
        '-----------------
        'Subtotal formula
        '-----------------
        'Build formula string
        formulaString = "=SUBTOTAL(109"
        For i = 13 To r - 13
            formulaString = formulaString & ",R[" & i & "]C"
            i = i + 11
        Next i
        formulaString = formulaString & ")"

        'Subtotal formulas
        .Range("I5:U6").FormulaR1C1 = formulaString
```

This works great until the references exceed 254. Is there an easy way build this R1C1 formula such that: For each cell in range I5:U6, SUBTOTAL 109 every 13th row beneath to max row? If there is an easy answer could you please explain it step by step? Thanks.

Comment: What happens when the references exceed 254?

Comment: SUBTOTAL only allows 254 references delimited by commas. When run in VBA the error is something like Error 1004: Application defined error.  If you try to manipulate the formula in Excel it will simply give you a formula error.

Comment: You can add a second loop to count until 254 and when you hit 254, close the formula string and reopen one, as in `formulaString = formulaString & ")+SUBTOTAL(109"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't sort your data to avoid that, or run the sum in a user defined function, you can add a second loop to count until 254 and when you hit 254, close the formula string and reopen one, as in this updated code:

```
    'Build formula string
    formulaString = "=SUBTOTAL(109"
    lCount=1
    For i = 13 To r - 13
        formulaString = formulaString & ",R[" & i & "]C"
        i = i + 11
        lcount=lcount+1
        if lcount>250 then 
           formulaString = formulaString & ")+ SUBTOTAL(109"
           lcount=1
        end if                        
    Next i
    formulaString = formulaString & ")"

    'Subtotal formulas
    .Range("I5:U6").FormulaR1C1 = formulaString
```

Comment: Interesting and simple solution, this works great. I've been looking for an OFFSET or ROW or something that I could use to give me every nth cell below a starting cell and the formula would be short and elegant. I'm not an excel expert and have been struggling trying to find something that works. Thanks much.

Answer (score 1):

Another option to total the 13th rows would be to use a `SUMPRODUCT` with `MOD`. This will not have the features of the subtotal, such as not totalling hidden rows, but it will be a simpler formula, e.g.:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A1:A100*(MOD(ROW($A$1:$A$100),13)=0))
```

Comment: I have to have the SUBTOTAL features. These formulas are for Totals cells at the top of the spreadsheet that provide a total of every 13th cell beneath in that column for visible, unfiltered rows. I was investigating this type of formula from Laurent Longre's page:   =SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(Rge,ROW(Rge)-MIN(ROW(Rge)),,1))) [link](http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2005/05/11/arrays-with-offset/)     but could not figure out how to apply it to my application. Adding R1C1 made it even more difficult to troubleshoot.